# Game Character - ArgumentError: Error #2109

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a Digital Media Arts student in my College. At the moment, we're using Actionscript3 to create a cross platform game as our final assignment.

I have created my character (a zombie), put him in a Movie Clip Symbol (named Zombie) and animated him (his movement, his death and his drop). I've put the animations (Labeled **Move**, **Pop** and **Xanim**).

The Actions are in the Scene, while the animations (labeled) are in the Movie Clip Symbol. Its basically a Code Snippet:

> zombie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
>   fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2);
>
> function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2(event:MouseEvent):void {
>       gotoAndPlay("Pop"); }

When I hit CTRL + Enter to test my character, he moves across the screen perfectly (I added the Code Snippet to Animate Horizontally). But when I click on him to make him pop (basically kill him), I get the following message in my Output:

> ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label Pop not found in scene Scene
>   1. at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop() at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2()

The "Pop" is located in my Movie Clip Symbol. Is there a way for me to code in Scene 1 so that I can use the Pop animation in my Movie Clip Symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're telling the main timeline to go to the "Pop" frame and it is saying there is no frame label called "Pop" in the main timeline.

The "Pop" label is inside your zombie, so you need to tell the zombie to go to that frame:

```
zombie.gotoAndPlay("Pop");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Now my character works perfectly :D